# Foundation - Launch modal on page load?

Tags: modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, onload

How exactly would I pull this off?

I just want to launch the modal when the page is loaded. Im using foundation/zurb

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can call the modal inside a document ready function

Because Foundation Javascript was designed to work with jQuery the following will work

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
}
```

Maybe there is also a way by customize the Foundation plugin initialization.
see [foundation javascript docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html)